# List all child projects of Parent in rally using rally java api

Tags: rally, alm

I am trying to all child projects under Parent project in rally.
I am able to get Children ref , but not sure how use it to get project names.
Below is my code: I am able to get Children ref in response , how do i get all children information like Name and other information

```
    QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest("Project");
            request.setFetch(new Fetch("Parent","Children", "Name", "FormattedId", "ObjectID"));
                String formattedProjectID = configuration.getProjectName();
            String projectId = findProjectObjectId(formattedProjectID);
            request.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("ObjectID", "=", projectId));
                request.setScopedDown(true);
            request.setProject("/project/" + projectId);        
                QueryResponse queryResponse = restApi.query(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is trigger another request to the Rally API using the `ref`.

Just add the following lines and you're all set; you'll get child projects in the JSON array:

```
GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(childRef);
getRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name"));
GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);
System.out.println(getResponse.getObject().getAsJsonArray("Results"));
```

*Please accept the answer if works fine ;-)*